# ASP.NET Get a single value returned from TableAdapter Select Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, tableadapter

I'm using TableAdapters on my ASP.NET Project and I've become stuck on an issue of the way to retrieve this data.

The code is as follows:

```
    BookingDataTableAdapters.bookingTableAdapter ta = new BookingDataTableAdapters.bookingTableAdapter();

    String booking_id_string = Request["id"];
    int booking_id = Int32.Parse(booking_id_string);


    BookingData.bookingDataTable table = ta.GetOwnerUsername(booking_id);

    String username = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        username = dr[0].ToString();
```

However this will error with the following:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

However when I run the query in the query builder, it runs fine without error. I've have also disabled "EnforceConstraints" inside the table adapter xsd file properties.

I've no idea what's wrong, is there a better way for me to get this single value back from my query in ASP.NET

Many thanks in advance, I appreciate the help :-)

Comment: Are you trying to get a single row back, or a single value? If it is the latter, I am not sure why you are using a table adapter.

Comment: I think its because he doesnt want to write any SQL... the table adapter should handle it all... then he plucks out the data value.  Its a heavy way to operate, but who is to tell him how to do his job... not me.

Comment: I just want a single value, but I'll be honest here, I don't know any other methods to get this data! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that tells me is that BookingData has been changed in the database and the object in your project was not updated.  When you get the row it cant fill the object because perhaps the database has a null and the object does not allow it.  Update the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the input, how do I go about force updating the dataset?

Comment: yikes, I dont know.  I think once they are generated you have to open the dataset, delete the table out of it, then drag it back on.  There could be a better way.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it, is there a better method to get this data that you would recommend?

Comment: yes, use a SqlDataReader!  You can just get the one value you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx